# Jenkins Not able to Deploy the application inside EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes

1. Having EKS cluster and up and running with single node group with version of 1.20
2. Then from Jenkins i configured cloud k8 to connect to my API server endpoint connection test also successes.
3. I deployed Jenkins via kubernetes yaml file and i have created dedicated namespace for Jenkins as well.

Here the complete file for jenkins role, rolebinding, serviceaccount and ns.

namespace.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: jenkins
```

RoleBinding.yaml

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins-role-binding
  namespace: jenkins
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: jenkins-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins-account
  namespace: jenkins
```

role.yaml

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-role
  namespace: jenkins
rules:
- apiGroups: [“”]
  resources: [“pods”]
  verbs: [“create”,”delete”,”get”,”list”,”patch”,”update”,”watch”]
- apiGroups: [“”]
  resources: [“pods/exec”]
  verbs: [“create”,”delete”,”get”,”list”,”patch”,”update”,”watch”]
- apiGroups: [“”]
  resources: [“pods/log”]
  verbs: [“get”,”list”,”watch”]
- apiGroups: [“”]
  resources: [“secrets”]
  verbs: [“get”]
- apiGroups: ["extensions", "apps"]
  #
  # at the HTTP level, the name of the resource for accessing Deployment
  # objects is "deployments"
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

service.account.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
 name: jenkins-account
 namespace: jenkins
 annotations:
  eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:sts::my-arn:assumed-role/DEVELOPER
```

Then finally I verified role as well

```
[root@ip-10-1-2-3 auto]# kubectl describe role jenkins-role -n jenkins
Name:         jenkins-role
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources               Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------               -----------------  --------------  -----
  deployments.apps        []                 []              [get list watch create update patch delete]
  deployments.extensions  []                 []              [get list watch create update patch delete]
  “pods.“”/exec”          []                 []              [“create” ”delete” ”get” ”list” ”patch” ”update” ”watch”]
  “pods”.“”               []                 []              [“create” ”delete” ”get” ”list” ”patch” ”update” ”watch”]
  “pods.“”/log”           []                 []              [“get” ”list” ”watch”]
  “secrets”.“”            []                 []              [“get”]
```

its seems everything looking fine but still jenkins not able to get right for the deployment while running pipeline build getting failed with below error.

```
Masking supported pattern matches of $KUBECONFIG
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
deploy to deployment!!
[Pipeline] sh
**+ kubectl auth can-i create deployments -n jenkins
no**
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```